# why titleForheaderInsection method in different table view controller not work?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

why `titleForheaderInsection` method in different table view controller not work?

I create two table view controllers in one storyboard for my app, with different function, one is `SettingsTableViewControlelr`, one is `CitylistTableViewControlelr`, and they should have different section titles.

`tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` method is used to name section title, but unfortunately only the method in `SettingsTableViewControlelr` has been appeared correctly in iOS simulator, but the method in `CitylistTableViewControlelr` is not work, i put a breakpoint on `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` method, and find the method even not be called in `CitylistTableViewControlelr`. Here is my code below:

> SettingsTableViewController

```
import UIKit

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> String? {
    switch section{
    case 0:
        return"Settings"
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
//the "tableView:titleForHeaderInSection" method in class SettingsTableViewController 
//is called and section title appears on simulator.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,heightForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("settingsIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    return cell
}    
}
```

> CitylistTableViewControlelr

```
import UIKit

class CityListTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForheaderInsection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return "Top Cities"
    case 1:
        return "Other Cities"
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
//Putting a breakpoint here, and find "tableView:titleForHeaderInSection" method in 
//CityListTableViewController is not even been called, thus the section titles, "Top Cities" & "Other Cities", 
//do not appear in simulator.I have tried to add "override" keyword before the method, but the 
//complier report error says "Method does not override any method from its superclass". 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,heightForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section{
    case 0:
        return 12
    case 1:
        return 15
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityListIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel!.text=topCitiesList[indexPath.row]
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel!.text=otherCitiesList[indexPath.row]
    default:
        cell.textLabel!.text="unknown"
    }
    return cell
}   
}
```

> My questions are:

1. Why `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` method not be called in `CityListTableViewController`?
2. How can I correct my code to make the section title appear on simulator/iPhone respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the differences between the two:

In the first view controller where it is being called, the function is being declared like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> String? {
    switch section{
```

Whereas in the one it isn't called it is being declared like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForheaderInsection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
```

You are missing the override declaration. Also, you didn't capitalize the "header" in the second declaration (Thanks for pointing that out Jesper).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried to add "override" keyword before the method, but the complier report error says "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

Comment: You typed it `titleForheaderInsection` and not `titleForHeaderInSection`. Selectors are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jesper & Yarneo. That's the reason caused the problem.